# How to use && operator in the case of switch statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

How to use && in the case of the switch? I want to convert this if-else into switch-case. Please help me I tried many options but didn't work any of them.

```
if( bpay <= 90000 &&  bpay >= 85000 )
{
System.out.println("You Job is General Manager");
}

if( bpay <= 84999 && bpay >= 75000 )
{
 System.out.println("Your Job is Manager" );
}

if ( bpay <= 74999 && bpay >= 65000 )
{
System.out.println("Your Job is Assistant Manager ");
}
if ( bpay <= 64999 && bpay >= 55000 )
{
System.out.println("Your Job is Accoutant");
}
if( bpay <= 54999 && bpay >= 40000 )
{
System.out.println("Your Job is Clerk");
}
if( bpay < 40000 )
System.out.println("You Job is Security Incharge");
```

Comment: Short: You can't!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are quite a number of similar questions already. If the linked one doesn’t suffice for you, please search. And generally do the same before posting a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Java. Switch was designed to identify unique cases.

P.S - Since, you're working with android, try Kotlin.
You can achieve it in kotlin using when (basically [switch but with superpowers](https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-when-statement/)).
For eg:

```
when(bpay) {
  in 40000..55000 -> println("Your Job is Clerk")
  in 55000..65000 -> println("Your Job is Accoutant")
  //Similarly for the rest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  This is not supported by the Java language.  It may work in others, but not here.  Cases must be an integer, string, or enum.  THey are not boolean statements

Answer (score 0):

Switch-case doesn't work on range, rather, it works on exact matches or constant values.

So, you **can't** convert this to switch-case, you have to use if-else here

Answer (score 0):

As said, that is not possible. Instead use `if-else-if`:

```
if ( bpay <= 90000 &&  bpay >= 85000 ) {
    System.out.println("You Job is General Manager");
} else if( bpay <= 84999 && bpay >= 75000 ) {
    System.out.println("Your Job is Manager" );
} else if ( bpay <= 74999 && bpay >= 65000 ) {
    System.out.println("Your Job is Assistant Manager ");
} else if ( bpay <= 64999 && bpay >= 55000 ) {
    System.out.println("Your Job is Accoutant");
} else if( bpay <= 54999 && bpay >= 40000 ) {
    System.out.println("Your Job is Clerk");
} else if( bpay < 40000 ) {
    System.out.println("You Job is Security Incharge");
}
```